# Get location of the control after hooking to Drawtext function

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have a VCL application that i'm testing but don't have the source code.
I need to validate what text was drawn to the labels on the screen but the labels are not a window so I create a hook to the drawtext function and i can get the text that was drawn to the screen.

But i cant validate where on the screen that text was drawn as the function gets hdc and a point where to draw the text in the context.
I need to figure where on the screen that hdc is located and make sure the the label is correct.

Is there a way to do it?
Managed unmanaged dose not matter to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to do something like this:

1. Call `WindowFromDC` to find out the window that hosts the label. As you know, a Delphi label is non-windowed and the control actually paints on its parent window. This may fail if the parent is double buffered. In that case you've no hope of getting the window handle from the device context since all you have is the device context of a bitmap.
2. Now that you have the window on which the label paints, you need to find out the location of the label on the window. The VCL calls `SetWindowOrgEx` to arrange that the device context has logical coordinates 0,0 at the top-left of the label. So you can call `GetWindowOrgEx` to find out the location of the label relative to the parent.
3. Now you know the location of the label relative to the parent, and the window handle of the parent, you can work out where the text is being drawn on screen with `ClientToScreen`.

Since device contexts only have meaning in the process that owns them, you'd need to inject into the target process to call this.

Comment: There's still hope. You just have to determine how the bitmap buffer eventually gets drawn to the screen. You can validate that the text is written to the correct location in the bitmap, so if you can validate that the bitmap is drawn to the correct location on the screen, then you're finished. An alternative may be to just compare the final screen image with a known-good image.

Comment: You have a idea how to validate where the bitmap is drawn?

Comment: Also can i change the double buffered from out side the process?

Comment: I did things similar to the ones David is talking about, but had to hook various "DC" and Bitmap APIs, too. A huge mess, if you ask.

Comment: I've created a delphi demo app that is not doubled buffered but i still get 0 when using WindowFromDC.
 IntPtr objHWND = WindowFromDC(hDC);

Comment: Working fine here. But of course I'm in-proc. You do need to inject into the target process in order to use the device context. I did not say that before because I thought it was obvious. I've added text to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a DLL in Delphi and inject that DLL in the target process. As your are happily hooking Win32 APis, I suppose you will not have problems with that.

In that DLL, you could find (using Win32 APIs) the HWND which is the "parent" of the Label.

With that HWND, you can find the associated `TWinControl`. For that you must dive into the VCL source code.

For Delphi 4 (yes, I know, it's old) you have to build an Atom String, use `GlobalFindAtom`, and then `GetProp`. The result is a pointer to the TWinControl.

For Delphi7 (old, too) you have to use `RegisterWindowMessage` with a string made up off "ControlOfs" followed by the module handle and the thread ID. The `LRESULT` of a `SendMessage` is then a pointer to the `TWinControl`.

Sorry, I don't know for other Delphi versions, but all should be findable in the VCL sources.

Once you have the `TWinControl` pointer, you can enumerate the children as `TComponent`, and get their `Name`'s (as they appear in the source code you don't have...),  their `ClassName`'s, and so on, you get the idea.

Comment: I will try this solution if all else fails. I will need to do this a few times for different delphi version.
Also i was hoping for a solution that will cover other languages also.

Comment: I you aim at general case, don't forget UIAutomation. But, imho, there is no silver Bullet.

Comment: UIAutomation won't help here because this is a non-windowed control and the VCL doesn't implement automation interfaces beyond that which comes for free with the standard Win32 controls.

Comment: - *".. (using Win32 APIs) the HWND which is the "parent" of the Label."* - As stated in the question, a label is not a window. What API are you suggesting to find its parent?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I am suggesting FindWindow or EnumWindows and all.

Comment: @manuell - I can't make any sense out of it. I repeat, as far as the API is concerned there's no label. You'll Find/Enum which window?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz You'll Find/Enum the window which you know is the first windowed component parent of the non-windowed child component.